# How to make video uploading and fetching performance even more fast

Tags: laravel, react-native, amazon-s3

Hey we are using `React Native` for app and `laravel` as a backend and `amazon s3` for video storing now our app is all about video uploading like tiktok and then getting video from s3 and playing it to user. We have done this but it is quite slow while uploading and slow while fetching the video as well. My question is, the best way to upload video fast and getting it fast as well. Any guidence would be apperiated.
Thank you

Comment: Video size is a major contributor to slowness in uploading and downloading speed. Do you compress the video before upload it?

Try to compress video at least up to 640 resolution and 16MB.

Comment: yes that is true. we did that but any other reason ?